# Pulseaudio not responding, every program that tries to access it freezes

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, freeze, alsa, realtek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I recently installed 12.04 (32-bit) on a new PC build (ASUS Sabertooth-Z77 motherboard with Realtek ALC892 audio chipset). I have no sound, the volume control panel applet doesn't show a slider, and I can't access the Sound Settings.

- Attempting to access the Sound Settings from the System Settings window causes that window to become non-responsive.
- Firefox and Chrome both become non-responsive when something in them triggers an audio event, e.g. attempting to play a flash video or receiving a message in FB.
- Banshee and Rhythmbox both become non-responsive immediately upon loading.
- Pulseaudio does not respond to CLI commands, including --kill.
- Attempting to play a .wav file from CLI with aplay hangs until I Ctrl+C it.

If I uninstall Pulseaudio, ALSA takes over and I get audio, but I couldn't get a panel applet to display or a volume button response even after attempting the instructions [here](http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/04/ubuntu-make-alsa-default-instead-of-pulseaudio/).

I tried purging pulseaudio, deleting ~/.pulse and reinstalling, to no effect.

aplay -l returns the following:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Not sure what else to try, any suggestions would be appreciated.